# What does "%&" mean in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I solved the [58th](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/58) 4clojure problem using recursion but then I looked at another persons solution and found this:

```
(fn [& fs] (reduce (fn [f g] #(f (apply g %&))) fs))
```

Which is more elegant than my solution. But I don't understand what `%&` means? (I do understand what `%` means but not when it's combined with `&`). Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means the "rest arguments", as per [this source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/API_Examples/Function_Tools).

> Arguments in the body are determined by the presence of argument
>   literals taking the form %, %n or %&. % is a synonym for %1, %n
>   designates the nth arg (1-based), and %& designates a rest arg.

Note that the `&` syntax is reminiscent of the `& more` arguments in function parameters ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797856/get-clojure-argument-list)), but `&%` works inside an [anonymous function shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204993/anonymous-function-shorthand).

Some code to compare anonymous functions and their anonymous function shorthand equivalent :

```
;; a fixed number of arguments (three in this case)
(#(println %1 %2 %3) 1 2 3)
((fn [a b c] (println a b c)) 1 2 3)

;; the result will be :
;;=>1 2 3
;;=>nil

;; a variable number of arguments (three or more in this case) :
((fn [a b c & more] (println a b c more)) 1 2 3 4 5)
(#(println %1 %2 %3 %&) 1 2 3 4 5)

;; the result will be :
;;=>1 2 3 (4 5)
;;=>nil
```

Note that the `& more` or `%&` syntax gives a list of the rest of the arguments.